# Serialization of part of nested xml file with varying properties

Tags: c#, xml, nested

I have along nested XML from which I wish to retrieve just a certain type of object. The xml structure is as follows:

```
<BaseTree> 
    <chunk> 
        <...> 
            <chunk number="1">
                <prop1>foo</prop1> 
                <prop2>bar</prop2>
            </chunk>
            <chunk number="2"> 
                <prop1>foo</prop1>  
            </chunk> 
        </...>
    </chunk>
</BaseTree>
```

I want to get the chunks with attribute "number" only. Those pieces have varying properties and are nested inside several `<chunk>` objects represented by the `<...>`.
I'm using C# but I'm quite a newbie, so try bearing this in mind :D

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I read a few solutions I found here, but none of them had all the peculiarities I am facing now. There are examples with nested classes, classes with properties, but I couldn't come out with a working solution so far :/